# What ticketing system can I use that will route a ticket to various admin groups, based on custom field input?

Tags: support-tracker

I need to find a ticketing system that has a very particular functionality.  I have a very large form, with three areas: Support, scheduling, and catering.  And I need the system to do this:

When the end-user fills out all three areas on the one single ticket form, a unique ticket will be sent out to each corresponding group admin, for a total of three different tickets.  In other words, the catering admin will get a ticket that has the catering info, the support admin will get a ticket with support info, etc.

I've seen SysAid and the use of categories, but their software doesn't quite do what I need.  I'm tasked with having only one form with all three of these areas, which will split off into three different tickets, as I mentioned above.

I need recommendations on what softwares can do this, please.  Also, my organization prefers a flat rate (as opposed to monthly fees) for the cost of this software (bonus points there).

Comment: Please [edit] your question. What is a 'ticketing system' **in your case** (the term is very broad), i.e. what requirements does it have? What 'form' are you talking about? What OS/online? What is an 'admin' in your case, an OS admin? 'Flat rate' and 'monthly fee' are not mutually exclusive - you really need to bring clear language into your question. Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: @JanDoggen, please see below.  I think the answers below clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: So you wanted a ticket system for support calls. **Then write so** instead of 'defending' your unclear question with a remark that brushes off people.

Comment: Mark, while [edit]ing your question to point out the missing details (see Jan's first comment), also take care for appropriate tags, please. We take some things rather serious, and have some quality standards we aim to match :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the described model doesn't allow end user to receive the feedback and communicate effectively with each group.

Let's imagine that information provided is not enough for the Support admin and he can't start working on the task. Another scenario: admin believes he resolved the task, but it's not exactly what end user wanted. Probably the description was not enough or there are mistakes (bugs).

That's why I would rather prefer to create tasks separately, but using hierarchy:

```
Your request as a parent task
    Support part subtask (assigned to Support admin)
    Scheduling part subtask (assigned to Scheduling admin)
    Catering part subtask (assigned to Catering admin)
```

I am using such functionality in [JIRA](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira). However, I believe there are many other tools that can do it.

Using this approach user and admin can move every subtask back and forth to make sure it meets end user's expectations.

Comment: That's an interesting point.  I need to share this with my group.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should take a look at [osTicket](http://osticket.com/) It is an open source support ticket system this can be hosted as

- Self Hosted
- Cloud Hosted

> Overview
>
> osTicket is a widely-used open source support ticket system. It
> seamlessly integrates inquiries created via email and web-based forms
> into a simple easy to use multi-user web interface. Easily manage,
> organize and archive all your support requests and responses in one
> place while providing your clients with accountability and
> responsiveness they deserve. osTicket is an attractive alternative to
> higher-cost and complex customer support systems; simple, lightweight,
> reliable, open source, and easy to setup and use. The best part is,
> it's completely free.

Features

- Web-based Platform : osTicket is a web-based multi-user customer
  support platform. No local installation required. Access it anytime -
  from anywhere.
- Customer Portal : All support requests and responses are archived
  online. User can login using email and ticket ID. No user account or
  registration required to submit a ticket.
- Autoresponder : Configurable automatic reply sent out when a new
  ticket is opened or a message is received.
- Email Integration : Tickets can be created via email, online forms or
  phone (created by staff). Flexible configuration and mapping.
- **Role-based Access : Control staff's access level based on assigned
  groups, departments and teams.**
- Collision Avoidance : Ticket locking mechanism to allow staff to lock
  tickets during response and avoid conflicting responses.
- Ticket Assignment : Assign tickets to a staff or a teams. Assignment
  notes are logged as internal notes.
- Ticket Transfer : Transfer tickets between departments to make sure
  it's being handled by the correct staff.
- Due Dates : Set due dates on individual tickets and overwrite default
  grace period. Get overdue alerts and notices on missed due dates.
- Alerts & Notices : Staff and clients are kept up to date with email
  alerts. Configurable and flexible settings.
- Dashboard & Reports : Get system overview and basic historical
  statistics on tickets count and status per department, staff and help
  topics.
- Canned Responses : Predefined responses for frequently asked
  questions. Ticket variables supported for personalized responses.
- Internal Notes : Add internal notes to tickets for staff. Activity
  logs let you see events or what actions have been taken, when, and by
  whom.
- Attachment Support : Allow web or emailed attachments. Configurable
  file type whitelisting to enhance security.
- Email Templates : Manage and configure email templates used for
  auto-reply, alerts, notices and responses. Ticket variables supported
  for personalized messages.
- Ticket Filters : Apply conditional rules to route incoming tickets to
  the right departments or staff members, and action triggers.
- Service Level Agreements : SLA support allow you to track tickets and
  due dates without the hassle. Get overdue alerts and notices on
  missed due dates, and priority escalation.

Soruce:[OsTicket Ratings](https://www.softaculous.com/apps/customersupport/osTicket)

***Most Importantly The official website of OSticket mentioned that***

> We can customize osTicket to meet your organization's specific needs.
> Contact us today and let us know how we can help streamline your
> customer support and ticket system.
> You Contact them via support@osticket.com

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

---

EDIT 2015_01_03

I dropped an email to the support and the reply was as follows,I will update this thread If I get more information

## 477907

> Thanks for your email and we apologize for the lack of clarity with
> our response. At this time, the system can not create three different
> tickets from one request. It is definitely something I will pass along
> to the developers for further review.

Comment: Thanks Pathum; I've looked at OSTicket before, but I'm still not clear if it can take one form (filled out by the end user) and split it into multiple tickets based on the multiple categories on the form that are filled out.

Comment: @Mark I sent an email to them let me check with them and get back to you :) !